# nginx as reverse proxy for daphne: 404 not found

Tags: azure, nginx, proxy, django-channels, daphne

Here's my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /proxy {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8001;     
    }
}
```

My server is virtual machine in azure.

When I go to http://13.65.102.226/proxy/ , it gives 404 not found.

and here's my supervisord.conf:

```
[program:runworker]
command=python /var/www/app/manage.py runworker
stopsignal=KILL
killasgroup=true

[program:daphne]
command=daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 app.asgi:channel_layer -v2

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried checking with `debug` on for the traceback?

Comment: change `proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8001;` to `proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8001/;   `

Answer (score 2):

I guess Nginx and Daphne are running on the same server. If so, try:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
```